# Display popup without security warning

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I use Silverlight and I'm trying to get some data to the user side. I can easily display PDF file with an `<embed>` tag in the browser.
However, I also have to be able to save files form the server. I tried the `SaveFileDialog` from Silvelright but it doesn't allow setting the file name (which is an issue).

I tried setting a hidden `<iframe>` source to the URL from the server but that triggers a security warning and it's not good either (there would be too many clueless users calling because it doesn't work).
I tried calling `window.open` to trigger a new popup set to the URL. That works OK but again there's a security warning.

Is it possible to get rid of that security message? I know it's possible in Javascript.
An exampel is on the site
http://livetecs.com
(go to the live demo, then project manager and open a report in a new window: no security warning!)
How do they achieve that behavior?

If there's any other way to get my reports saved Silverlight I'd be very interested to hear about them.

EDIT: The warning I'm talking about is the `Pop-up blocked. To see this pop-up or additional options click here..` banner appearing on top of the page.

Cheers.

Comment: Which security warning? Something about the domain? Something about how it goes to an unencrypted page?

Comment: I edited my question. I'm talking about the regular "pop-up blocked" warning. Extra annoyance for Silverlight is that it triggers a client refresh (ie the Silverlight plugin reloads).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around the pop up blocker when you open up a window without a user action. If there was a way around that, than the pop up blockers would be useless.

Only way to avoid the security message is to have the users add your site to their safe list.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after much fiddling I came accross the Silverlight built-in pop-up window that I couldn't use before.

The only limitation is that it can only be triggered by a user action (which is fine in this context() [PopUpWindow at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmlpage.popupwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx)

It fits the bill perfectly and I couldn't use it before because I wanted to pre-generate the report files before opening the pop-up (and thus I wasn't in a user event context anymore).

I'm going to create a report generation page that will display a status message and then show the report (I haven't worked out yet how I'll do that though).

Comment: A point to be aware of with PopUpWindow is that it doesn't work in Safari at all.